# Importing Vue JS component raises "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm quite new to `Vue.js` and I'm trying to use it in my `Django` project. I need to import `vue-google-autocomplete` but i receive the following error:

```
 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
```

The problem is in this line:

```
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'
```

I don't use any package managers (like `npm`) and I'm trying to use just `html` to import libraries.

This is the code:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&callback=onLoaded&language=sk&region=SR"
            async defer></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-google-autocomplete@1.1.0/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue" type="application/octet-stream"></script>
    <script>

        import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'

        Vue.component('vue-google-autocomplete', VueGoogleAutocomplete);
        var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                address: '',
                business_type_text: '',
            },
            methods: {
               ....
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

I've created a new file `create.js` which I import after `vue.js` and the autocomplete cdn but it still raises an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Vue.use(vue-google-autocomplete)`

You might need to replace the name.

`import` cannot be recognize by the JavaScript interpreter. It needs to be transpiled first.

If you want to use `import`, you must create a file (i.e. main.js) and include it in your HTML file like this:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></
```

Comment: I've created create.js and used Vue.use('vue-google-autocomplete') but the component isn't loaded at all.

Comment: From the source, the name of the component is VueGoogleAutocomplete. Maybe Vue.use(VueGoogleAutocomplete)