# Vue.js - how to import a component? (MIME type error)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new in `Vue.js` and I'm trying to use https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete component.

I've downloaded this file: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-google-autocomplete@1.1.0/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue`

And added to my static folder.

Then I've created `create.js` where I'm importing the module.

```
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from '/static/addresses/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue'

Vue.component('vue-google-autocomplete',VueGoogleAutocomplete);
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',
    ...
```

But **Chrome** raises error when I reload the page:

```
VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Are you transpiling down to es5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Vue JS component raises "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039916/importing-vue-js-component-raises-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)

Answer (score -2):

Can't your install it with npm or yarn ?

> npm install vue-google-autocomplete --save

Or

> yarn add vue-google-autocomplete

Then import it

```
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'
```

Comment: I don't use it it's a django project so I prefer non packege manager solution.

Comment: So you're using the import statement as-is in the browser ? I'm affraid ou won't be able to load .vue files that way.

Maybe this can help https://medium.com/@jamesweee/using-vue-js-single-file-component-without-module-bundlers-aea58d892ad9